# Is it possible to have folders in v2 python Azure functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

According to the Azure docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#folder-structure

They have all the files at the repo, but if I wanted to have a bunch of different functions in the same function app, how can I organize them in folders?

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy different Functions in a same Function app, Refer the steps below:-

According to this [**Microsoft Blog**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model-is-generally/ba-p/3827474) on **`Function V2 programming model`**. In order to reduce multiple Folders and File management, You need to add multiple Azure Function triggers in the same function_app.py with multiple output and input bindings:-

> [image]

**My** ***function_app.py with Http_Trigger and Queue_Trigger binding and decorators***:-

```py
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello") # HTTP Trigger
def test_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse("HttpTrigger1 function processed a request!!!")

@app.queue_trigger(arg_name="azqueue", queue_name="testqueue",
                               connection="testqueue") 
def queue_trigger(azqueue: func.QueueMessage):
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**Local Output:-**

[image]

I deployed this **Function in my Function app and both the triggers were visible**:-

[image]

*Add below settings in the Environment Variables:-*

```
[
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "python",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "value": "InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxd825aa;IngestionEndpoint=https://australiacentral-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://australiacentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=vsidrgb561;AccountKey=xxxxxxxAStiabOIw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=vsidrgb561;AccountKey=xxxxxxxx73S3IgpyqEx+AStiabOIw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
    "value": "siliconfunc98bdd9",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "BUILD_FLAGS",
    "value": "UseExpressBuild",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "XDG_CACHE_HOME",
    "value": "/tmp/.cache",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "testqueue",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg989;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxFKHm/A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags",
    "value": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

```
AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags:EnableWorkerIndexing
```

Below setting is mandatory for the Functions to load in the Function App.

[image]

Comment: I see. However, this doesn't help my use case. It wouldn't be organizationally beneficial to include a bunch of azure functions in one function_app.py - this would lead to clutter. I have already somewhat gotten it to work using az function "blueprints" which lets me separate out my functions in their own files and lets me have a cleaner funtction_app.py that consolidates each function. I wanted to know if I could put these blueprint scripts in folders. Sorry for not providing more context sooner

Comment: Yes, You can put separate triggers in separate blueprint folders and call them in your function_app.py

Comment: Hmm but what about the function.json file where you specify triggers? Do you specify both in there or only one, or neither?