# How to Debug Multiple project Azure Functions Python V2 in VSCode

Tags: python, azure, debugging, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have created 2 Python (V2 Programming model) Azure Functions in Vs Code and used a workspace. When I click F5 or start debugging, only the first project session starts debugging, but not the second. When I use func start in terminal for second project, it starts the project but I need to debug rather than just run. Following are my configuration files -

**Launch.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Preferences",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9091,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
            "project": "${workspaceFolder}/API.Preferences"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Charts",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 7071,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start", 
            "project": "${workspaceFolder}/API.Charts"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Settings.json**

```
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguageModel": 2,
    "azureFunctions.projectSubpath": "API.Charts"
}
```

**Tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/API.Preferences"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/API.Preferences"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**code.workspace.json file**

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": ".."
        },
        {
            "path": "../API.Preferences"
        },
        {
            "path": "../API.Charts"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": [
            {
                "name": "Attach to both apps",
                "configurations": [
                    "Attach to Preferences",
                    "Attach to Charts"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Refer my [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506062/is-it-possible-to-have-folders-in-v2-python-azure-functions/77514766#77514766)

> According to this [**Microsoft Blog**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model-is-generally/ba-p/3827474) on **`Function V2 programming model`**. In order to reduce multiple Folders and File management, You need to add multiple Azure Function triggers in the same function_app.py with multiple output and input bindings

Thus instead of creating separate folders for each Function Trigger, You need to add both the triggers in the same **`function_app.py`** file for it to debug together. As, You have created Function project separately in another folder, you need to manually visit the specific Function Project folder root and run func host start to run and debug the individual Function. If you want to keep the Function triggers in separate file you can create blueprint implementation by referring my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77731886/deploying-multiple-functions-to-same-function-app/77732010#), Where I have referenced 2 of my SO threads for the blueprint and multiple folder implementation.

**`function_app.py:-`**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

I have created **`Http_trigger`** then added **`Timer_trigger`** in the same file, You can also create separate blueprint file for the same:-

[image]

**Output:-**

I clicked **`fn + F5 button`** or **`F5`** and both the Functions got executed together:-

[image]